# Yocto build error for python and qt5

Tags: linux, python-2.7, qt5, yocto

I'm getting below yocto build error and I'm not sure what is the problem.
I am trying to build yocto for my warpx board. Able to build headless image but not headfull.
Can you please anyone point out any issue ?
I have used yocto krogoth version with freescal platform bsp.

These are the commands I followed.

```
repo init -u https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform -b krogoth
repo sync
cd sources
git clone https://github.com/Kynetics/meta-warpx.git
cd meta-warpx
git checkout krogoth
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5.git
cd meta-qt5
git checkout krogoth
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate.git
cd meta-swupdate
git checkout krogoth
cd ../../
cp -rf sources/meta-warpx/first-setup/setup-warpx-warp .
source setup-warpx-warp
ACCEPT the terms here (say 'y')
Now we are in "~/yocto/build-warpx-warp" location.
cp -rf ../sources/meta-warpx/first-setup/local.conf.sample conf/local.conf
cp -rf ../sources/meta-warpx/first-setup/bblayers.conf conf/
bitbake warpx-headfull-image-sdk

titus@titusPC:~/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp$ bitbake warpx-headfull-image

WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-16.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Loading cache: 100% |################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 2562 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |##############################################################| Time: 00:00:00
Parsing of 1997 .bb files complete (1996 cached, 1 parsed). 2562 targets, 192 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.30.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "warp"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.1.3"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon       callconvention-hard       cortexa9"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta              
meta-poky         = "HEAD:3565a9697f53ba975a1b7235b802f659418746c3"
meta-oe           
meta-multimedia   
meta-networking   
meta-python       = "krogoth:55c8a76da5dc099a7bc3838495c672140cedb78e"
meta-fsl-arm      = "HEAD:e2254e7b2ded0c2b66b1226f879b3a6d52037b2d"
meta-fsl-arm-extra = "HEAD:2c28e636ec15c2cfd49bc9cebe0bbbcfde95bc7b"
meta-qt5          = "krogoth:1100037b9becaaa5749602bca9d63693119c4585"
meta-warpx        = "krogoth:b2110ade3cd53f3b98a8f057d508c075b4d691e2"
meta-swupdate     = "krogoth:712d4aee92ea3a23952a3e7fb812e5c4df7492ec"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: python-pyqt-5.3.1-r1 do_generate: Error calling sip on QtCore
ERROR: python-pyqt-5.3.1-r1 do_generate: Function failed: do_generate (log file is located at /home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-pyqt/5.3.1-r1/temp/log.do_generate.2080)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-pyqt/5.3.1-r1/temp/log.do_generate.2080
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_generate
| NOTE: using modules 'QtCore QtGui QtQml QtQuick QtSvg QtWebKit QtWidgets QtOpenGL QtXmlPatterns' and tags '-tWS_X11 -tQt_5_3_1 -xVendorID -xPyQt_Accessibility -xPyQt_Desktop_OpenGL -xPyQt_SessionManager'
| calling 'sip4 -I sip -I /home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/sip -tWS_X11 -tQt_5_3_1 -xVendorID -xPyQt_Accessibility -xPyQt_Desktop_OpenGL -xPyQt_SessionManager  -c QtCore -b QtCore/QtCore.pro.in sip/QtCore/QtCoremod.sip'
| /home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-pyqt/5.3.1-r1/temp/run.do_generate.2080: 137: /home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-pyqt/5.3.1-r1/temp/run.do_generate.2080: sip4: not found
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Error calling sip on QtCore
| ERROR: Function failed: do_generate (log file is located at /home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-pyqt/5.3.1-r1/temp/log.do_generate.2080)
ERROR: Task 3512 (/home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/sources/meta-warpx/recipes-devtools/python/python-pyqt_5.3.1.bb, do_generate) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3319 tasks of which 2678 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/titus/workdir/Titus/yocto/sources/meta-warpx/recipes-devtools/python/python-pyqt_5.3.1.bb, do_generate
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
titus@titusPC:~/workdir/Titus/yocto/build-warpx-warp$
```

Comment: It seems you have to ad sip to your image.

Comment: A possible reason for the defect dependency (which this basically seems to be) might be the mixed releases: HEAD for poky+fsl-arm, krogoth for everything else. This absolutely screams for problems.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to doesn't have the `sip` recipe in your `yocto` source.
`python-pyqt` depends on sip add the `sip` recipe and compile again.

Comment: How to add the `sip` recipe and compile again?